# An optimization version of 2QBF: is it $\mathsf{NP}^{\mathsf{NP}}$-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, decision-problem, propositional-logic

I am studying the computational complexity of the following decision problem related to 2QBF:

- Input: a 3-CNF formula $\varphi$ over $X \cup Y$, where $X$, $Y$ are disjoint sets of propositional variables, and an integer $k \geq 0$.
- Question: does there exists an assignment of the variables from $X$ such that all assignments of the variables from $Y$ satisfy at least $k$ clauses from $\varphi$?

Is this problem $\mathsf{NP}^{\mathsf{NP}}$-hard?

Despite the problem being in $\mathsf{NP}$ for the case where all clauses in $\varphi$ are required to be satisfied, to me the problem above seems to be $\mathsf{NP}^{\mathsf{NP}}$-hard. But while a number of works can be found when the two quantifiers are reversed (i.e., when the first quantifier is universal and the second quantifier is existential), I cannot manage to find the problem stated above studied in the literature.

Comment: Are $X,Y$ part of the input? If so, this is almost $\Sigma_2 SAT$

Comment: Isn't $\Sigma_2SAT$ the problem of deciding whether the QBF $\forall X \exists Y \varphi$ is valid? My point is precisely that in the problem I consider, the QBF is of the form $\exists X \forall Y \varphi$, and that at least $k$ clauses in $\varphi$ must be satisfied (not necessarily all clauses must be satisfied, otherwise the problem falls in $\mathsf{NP}$)

Comment: $\Sigma_2 SAT$ consists of true formulas of the form $\exists u_1 \forall u_2 \varphi(u_1,u_2)$ where $\varphi$ is a CNF and $u_1,u_2$ are vectors of boolean variables.

Comment: @Ariel, are you sure? user109711 has explained patiently to me that $\exists u_1 \forall u_2 \varphi(u_1,u_2)$ is in NP.  Given a value of $u_1$ (the witness), one can check in polynomial time whether $\forall u_2 \varphi(u_1,u_2)$ holds, by checking one clause at a time.

Comment: @D.W. Got me there. I just checked Arora & Barak's book and they indeed mention that the formula is not necessarily a CNF (the same is obviously true of the language Tautology which is famously coNP complete).